# what is the message "P.S We are running a small javascript miner...." on blogspot

Tags: browser, virus, javascript, data-mining, cryptomining

I have created a blog to share some important question and answers with my friends. But when I open the blogspot link on edge browser it shows some abnormal behavior like computer becoming very slow.

[screenshot from edge browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awTGT.jpg)
I don't know what does it mean.In image Hashes/s and threads are fluctuating, Total is continuously increasing but Speed remains 100 percent. I am afraid of ransomware or any kind of hacking.

It is working fine with all other browsers.

Thanks in advance sorry for bad English(I am working on it :))

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency

Comment: Rather https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting and https://hackerbits.com/programming/what-is-cryptojacking/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you mistyped the URL as `blogsopt.com` and landed on a cybersquatter's page which helpfully redirected you to the page you intended to load but also loaded a cryptocurrency miner.

Just close the tab with the miner and enter in the correct URL next time.

Answer (score 1):

See [Typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting). You misspelled the "blogspot.com" part of your URL, and you loaded `blogsopt.com`. Apparently the owner of this `blogsopt.com` is mining Monero [cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency) (with CoinHive it looks like), using the visitor's processing power, while behaving as a mirror for the actual Blogspot page you're looking for. Your computer should be safe, since it's just a JavaScript coin miner, but since you're at the mercy of this joker running a common typo domain, I would check around to make sure nothing is amiss.

Answer (score -2):

I also used to face same issue on my website [Wheel of Names](https://www.wheelofnames.fun/) after doing research i found that the message "P.S We are running a small javascript miner..." on Blogspot is not a standard or common message that you would find on the Blogspot platform. It's possible that someone added this message to a specific blog or website hosted on Blogspot, but without more context or information, it's difficult to determine the exact meaning or purpose behind the message.

A "javascript miner" typically refers to a script that runs in a web browser to mine cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin using the visitor's computational resources. This practice, known as "cryptojacking," is generally considered unethical and is often done without the user's consent. However, it's crucial to note that using such scripts without the user's knowledge and consent is a violation of most platforms' terms of service and could potentially be illegal.

If you encounter this message on a Blogspot blog or any website, it is advisable to avoid interacting with the website further and report it if you suspect any malicious activity. Keep in mind that the online landscape is continually changing,

Comment: The author didn’t actually go to the correct URL.

Comment: Its already been answered and accepted. How dies this help?